# DirectX vs winapi BitBlt - перформанс вывода Bitmap

Tags: c++, winapi, графика, directx

Есть ли приемущества по `скорости вывода`/`нагрузке на пооцессор` при выводе Bitmap (HBITMAP) используя нечто отличное от `winapi` (BitBlt), например `DirectX`.

Bitmap'ы статичные, но могут часто меняться в определенном режиме, примерно 2-5 раз в секунду, зависит от внешних факторов. Усреднённые параметры изображений примерно 1200х800, 24bpp, размер 3-4Мб в не сжатом виде.

Интересуют практические наблюдения, если смысл связываться для увеличения скорости реендеринга?

Возможно оптимальней будет использовать что-то отличное от `DirectX`?

Comment: здесь важно понимать, что методы отрисовки в сравнении с одной стороны StretchDIBits,BitBlt и DirectX, OpenGl с другой стороны первый вариант в разы будет уступать, так как отрисовкой занимается цп. Используя второй вариант у вас скорость будет зависеть от видеокарты в основном

Comment: в данном случае, используются изображения, довольно тяжелые, скорее всего bmp формат. Если картинки подгружаются не сразу(во время запуска программы), а по мере необходимости, то на скорость отображения будет влиять жесткий диск.

Comment: Картинки получаются условно из сети, на самом деле через USB, диск не задействован. BitBlt и его производные оптимизировались многие годы, отсюда и сомнения, будет ли быстрее.. рисовать то все равно в окно.

Comment: даже если видеокарта интегрированная(видеокартой является проц), то все равно отрисовка будет быстрее через библиотеки. Так как они разработаны и оптимизированы специально под эту функцию, а BitBlt это функция старая, если и были оптимизации, то только для совместимости WinAPI с новыми OS. Она не как с видеокартой не взаимодействует, все делает проц

Comment: Я думаю, использование функций GDI при разработке новых приложений нежелательно, хотя бы потому, что GDI занесен в "Deprecated or legacy APIs" на этой странице: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/apiindex/windows-api-list#deprecated-or-legacy-apis При выводе 2-5 кадров в секунду разница между DirectX и GDI вряд ли будет заметна, но все равно, вечно сидеть на этих старых функциях как-то не очень...

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, вот я тоже придерживаюсь такого мнения `выводе 2-5 кадров в секунду разница между DirectX и GDI..` - правда оно не мотивированно практикой, по этому хочется услышать мнения тех кто непосредственно пробывал реализовывать подобные задачи. А что более оптимально на замену GDI сегодня?

Comment: [Direct2D](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Direct2D/direct2d-portal). Либо Direct3D 9, если есть необходимость поддержки старых ОС. Так, для информации: WPF использует именно Direct3D 9 для рендеринга.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. И GDI (BitBlt), и DirectX, и Direct2d являются подсистемами WinAPI.
2. И GDI (частично), и DirectX, и Direct2d (частично) поддерживают аппаратное ускорение. У GDI был период после перехода на WDDM 1.0 при выпуске Windows Vista когда аппаратного ускорения не было совсем, однако с переходом на WDDM 1.1 его вернули. см [Specifying GDI Hardware-Accelerated Rendering Operations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/specifying-gdi-hardware-accelerated-rendering-operations). А Direct2D использует DirectX.
3. Просто вывод битмапа 1200х800 несколько раз в секунду - это совершенно несущественная операция в плане вычислительных затрат. На самом деле большая часть времени будет тратится на передачу этой картинки и команд на GPU, чем непосредственно на отрисовку.
4. Другое дело, что возможности DirectX намного шире. Плюс DirectX поддерживается в приложениях для магазина Windows.
5. "*увеличения скорости реендеринга*" - а что, у вас сейчас есть проблемы со скоростью рендеринга? Если вопрос ставить таким образом, то необходимо приводить конкретный тест и конкретные результаты.